# Angular JS Component Bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I am having trouble making the item looped from an ng-repeat from a parent component available to the scope of a nested component. The parent component is a carousel which contains many item components. The carousel is populated by the ng-repeat. I want to be able to access the "item" and a method of the carousel controller ("cr") in the item controller ("it"). I guess I am going about this in the totally wrong way. Appreciate if anyone can give me a steer.

carousel.component.html

```
<slick <!--slick attributes--> >
     <div ng-repeat="item in cr.items">
            <item-component></item-component>
     </div>
</slick>
```

carousel.component.js

```
class CarouselController{
  constructor(/*stuff*/){
    'ngInject';    

     this.items =[
       {"something":"The thing 1","otherthing":"The other thing 1"},
       {"something":"The thing 2","otherthing":"The other thing 2"},
       {"something":"The thing 3","otherthing":"The other thing 3"}
     ];
  }

  parentFunctionToCall(item){
    console.log('I called a function on the parent!',item)
  }

  /*other stuff*/
}

export const CarouselComponent = {
  templateUrl: './views/app/components/carousel/carousel.component.html',
  controller: CarouselController,
  controllerAs: 'cr',
  bindings: {
  }
}
```

item.component.html

```
<div data-something="{{item.something}}">
  Yo,{{item.otherthing}}!
</div>

<a href="#" ng-click="cr.parentFunctionToCall(item)">
   Trying to call a function on the parent component
</a>
```

item.component.js

```
class ItemController{
  constructor($scope,/*stuff*/){
    'ngInject';

     //$scope.it.item & $scope.it.cr are both undefined
     console.log(this);

     //I understand this is the incorrect way but it works
     this.$scope.item = this.$scope.$parent.item;
     console.log(this);
  }

  /*other stuff*/
}

export const ItemComponent = {
  templateUrl: './views/app/components/carousel/item.component.html',
  controller: ItemController,
  controllerAs: 'it',
  bindings: {
    "item":"=",//i can see this as undefined $scope in ItemController
    "cr":"=" //i want to access a method on the parent controller
  }
}
```

This shows whats up...
https://plnkr.co/edit/UG20EtI4KxnVnTe8zzz4?p=preview

Comment: please update your code into a working snippet and i'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: @PhilPoore incoming, much appreciated

Comment: @PhilPoore if your offer still stands - https://plnkr.co/edit/UG20EtI4KxnVnTe8zzz4?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly simple in the end.. I am not sure why this isnt made clearer in the documentation but its as easy as setting an attribute on the child component:

```
<slick <!--slick attributes--> >
  <div ng-repeat="item in cr.items">
        <!--new item="item" attr-->
        <item-component item="item" call-parent="cr.parentFunctionToCall(item)"></item-component>
  </div>
</slick>
```

Then the binding works as expected. Accessing a function on the parent behaves a similar way. Some event name needs to be added as an attribute (`call-parent` but this can be anything). The binding needs to be added to the child component (as in @kuhnroyals comment):

```
...
bindings: {
  item:"=",
  callParent: '&'
}
```

And some interaction event on the child component eg `ng-click="it.callParent()"`

Working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RIOPs6?p=preview

Comment: You can bind a function the same way by using the `&` binding. `onDelete`  and `onUpdate` are just examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using `controllerAs` you don't have a `$scope`, you need to use `this`. Especially with components.

```
this.items =[
   {"something":"The thing 1","otherthing","The other thing 1"},
   {"something":"The thing 2","otherthing","The other thing 2"},
   {"something":"The thing 3","otherthing","The other thing 3"}
 ];
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Thanks - edited. Still not getting the stuff from the parent

Comment: You don't have parent scopes, they are always isolated scopes. See the link. You can require the parent controller and inject it.

Comment: Yeah I understand but I thought that via bindings I should be able to make scope from the parent element (ie the div with the ng-repeat) available to the `item-component` within the ng-repeat. Surely that is possible somehow without doing the hacky stuff accessing `$scope.$parent.item` (which does work but defeats the isolated scope idea)

Comment: in reference to the doc what I am talking about is the "Intercomponent Communication" in a "Component Tree"

Comment: When yu look at the table in the link, you have two options, either by using `bindings` or `require`. It seems you now found the first way, which is the better one.